# Volley String post request from a curl command

Tags: android-volley

I am trying get access-token. By using curl/commnad window i can get it but i need to use android volley. Volley shows error says unexpected response code. Here is curl command:

$ curl "https://api.*****.com/auth/oauth/v2/token" \

--insecure  \

--header "Accept: application/json"   \

--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  \

--data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=9d40008a9a4-438b-800c-dec6486a7631"\

--data 
“client_id=l7xxdedc2c3d49e58459287fe66092ad&client_secret=fa48a352e633841695b1d969750" \

--data "scope=scope_test&state=state_test" \

--data "redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000" \

--request POST$

I have written an equivalent Volley string request. I dont know where is my mistake? Why it is not giving me the response. Please help me

```
 StringRequest postRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d("accessToken:",response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("error:",volleyError.toString());

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public byte[] getPostBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            String grantcode=preference.getAccessToken();
            String httpPostBody="grant_type=authorization_code&code="+grantcode+"&client_id=l7xx5a227281eb364ab3bb6fd8cc49648427&client_secret=c29a24fad90640f993770f07a5e77892&scope=scope_test&state=state_test";
            return httpPostBody.getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<String,String>();
            headers.put("Accept","application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }

    };
            ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
        }
    });
```

Even i tried to use getBody instead of getPostBody. But it did not solve my problem. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Here is the way:

```
StringRequest postRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d("accessToken:",response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("error:",volleyError.toString());

        }
    }){


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("grant_type","authorization_code");
            params.put("code",preference.getGrantCode());
            params.put("client_id", Resources.CLIENT_ID);
            params.put("client_secret",Resources.CLIENT_SECRET);
            params.put("scope","scope_test");
            params.put("state","state_test");
            params.put("redirect_uri",Resources.REDIRECT_URI );
            return params;

        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<String,String>();
            headers.put("Accept","application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }

    };
            ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. 
Putting --data values in to body solved for me.